# SpringBoot RestAPI Controller methods are not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I wrote a few service methods. When I implement `CommandLineRunner` to my `SpringApplication` and try to execute service methods in run methods I can see they're working.

I mean like this approach,  I can reach the data via service methods. So I can say yes my services are working right.

```
      public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

      postService.getAllPost()
            .stream()
            .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getTitle()));

      }
```

But When I try to use my controllers via postman.  For the User class, everything is fine.

```
  public List<UserDto> getAllUsers() {

    return userRepository.findAll()
            .stream()
            .map(userMapper::toDto)
            .collect(toList());
   }


       @GetMapping("/get")
public ResponseEntity<List<UserDto>> getAll() {

    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getAllUsers());
}
```

But Comment and Post are not working.
The methods are almost same. I was wondering is it about my entities relation? Because in User entity I just have 3 different field which is Long, String , String . But the other  entities are related with each others. With OneToMany relational. And I dont trust about my business plan. I mean post class includes user and comment object. Comment class includes user object etc.

This is controller method.

```
@GetMapping("/getAll")

 public ResponseEntity<List<CommentDto>> fetchAll() {

    return ResponseEntity.ok(commentService.getAllComments());
 }
```

This is service method.

```
  public List<CommentDto> getAllComments() {

    return commentRepository.findAll().stream()
            .map(commentMapper::toDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

 }
```

I have three different entity class.

Which is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_table")
public class User{

@Id
private Long id;
private String userName;
private String password; 
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "post_table")
public class Post {

@Id
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id" , nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private User user;

private String title;
@Lob
@Column(columnDefinition = "text")
private String text;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "comment_table")

public class Comment {

@Id
private Long id;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id" , nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private Post post;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id" , nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private User user;

@Lob
@Column(columnDefinition = "text")
private String text;
```

Comment: "They're not working" => What does that mean exactly? Do you get an error message? If so, then what is the error message?

Comment: {
    "timestamp": "2022-04-12T11:43:27.628+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/v1/api/comment/getAll"
}

Comment: Do you see anything in the logging on the server?

Comment: It gives Internal Server Error for existing users.  For the non existing users it gives 400 Bad Request.

Comment: @eagerdev You do not have "user" parameter in your rest api or service method. Is there something that you don't share?

Comment: you are getting null pointer exception, public List<CommentDto> getAllComments() is failing